# Erro na passagem de parâmetros C#

Tags: c#

Estou com o seguinte erro:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'
```

No seguinte código:

```
t.Codigo = GetValorDateTime(tabela, i, "DataDeContrato", DateTime.MinValue);

    public DateTime GetValorDateTime(DataTable pDados, int pLinha, String pNomeColuna, DateTime pValorPadrao)
    {
        DateTime retorno = pValorPadrao;
        if (pDados.Rows.Count > pLinha)
        {
            if (pDados.Columns.Contains(pNomeColuna))
            {
                object valor = pDados.Rows[pLinha].ItemArray[pDados.Columns[pNomeColuna].Ordinal];
                if (valor != null)
                    retorno = Convert.ToDateTime(valor);
            }
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu `t.Codigo` deve ser do tipo string, e o retorno do método é do tipo `DateTime`.

você pode tentar fazer assim:

```
t.Codigo = GetValorDateTime(tabela, i, "DataDeContrato", DateTime.MinValue).ToString();
```

Mas acredito que não seja isso que você queira, um DateTime não faz sentido como Codigo de alguma coisa. Talvez está errando a propriedade que deseja definir, possívelmente:

```
t.DataDeContrato = GetValorDateTime(tabela, i, "DataDeContrato", DateTime.MinValue);
```

Comment: Ops, era isso mesmo. Esqueci de alterar o nome após o CTRL+C CTRL+V hshshs